# Creating XML Document in C# - Appending an XML string as "Xmlelement"

Tags: c#, xml, reporting-services, xmldocument

I am trying to append a string to xml document.
I wanna create RDLC in c# and build the xml.
I need to cast or convert a string generated dynamically in the code c# and import it into the "TablixBody" tag.
Here's the code:

```
 <!-- Generating the XmlDocument in c# --> 
           
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Report xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition" xmlns:rd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner">
   <Body>
      <ReportItems>
         <Tablix Name="SOPaymentDetails">
            <TablixBody>
               <TablixColumns>
                  <TablixColumn>
                     <Width>10.83106in</Width>
                  </TablixColumn>
               </TablixColumns>
            </TablixBody>
         </Tablix>
      </ReportItems>
   </Body>
</Report>
```

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like will be of some help :

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("rootdoc.xml");
```

rootdoc.xml may have your intial code.
Then you do this :

```
XElement tagbody= doc.Elements("TablixBody")[0]:
tagbody.Add(content);
```